# App crashes after tap on UITextField in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitextfield

I created an app for iOS in VS with Xamarin. It works well both on iOS Simulator and real devices, but once I get a message from the user, that app crashes after a tap on UITextField. This is default iOS UITextField on the login screen. Strange, that this crash appears only on iPhone 6s with iOS v10.2.1. On iPhone with iOS >= v10.3 this crash doesn't appear.

This UITextField has only one event overriding

```
loginInput.EditingChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    UITextField textInput = (UITextField)s;
    if (textInput.Text.Length == 10)
    {
        textInput.ResignFirstResponder();
    }
    else if (textInput.Text.Length > 10)
    {
        char[] originalText = textInput.Text.ToCharArray();
        char[] maskedText = new char[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            maskedText[i] = originalText[i];
        }
        textInput.Text = new string(maskedText);
        textInput.ResignFirstResponder();
    }
};
```

Also, I use **UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow** and **UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide** in **ViewWillAppear** overriding to translate the whole view depending on keyboard height. It's needed because otherwise, keyboard hides UITextField and user can't see, what he types.

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

    UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow((s, e) =>
    {
        var r = UIKeyboard.FrameEndFromNotification(e.Notification);
        keyboardHeight = r.Height;
        _originalPosition = mainPageView.Center.Y;
        if (keyboardHeight == 0)
        {
            keyboardHeight = r.Height;
        }
        Action keyboardShift = () => {
            var xpos = mainPageView.Center.X;
            var ypos = mainPageView.Center.Y - keyboardHeight;
            mainPageView.Center = new CGPoint(xpos, ypos);
        };
        UIViewPropertyAnimator propertyAnimator = new UIViewPropertyAnimator(0.25, UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut, keyboardShift);
        propertyAnimator.StartAnimation();
    });
    UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide((s, e) =>
    {
        var r = UIKeyboard.FrameEndFromNotification(e.Notification);
        keyboardHeight = r.Height;
        if (keyboardHeight == 0)
        {
            keyboardHeight = r.Height;
        }
        Action keyboardUnShift = () => {
            var xpos = mainPageView.Center.X;
            var ypos = _originalPosition;
            mainPageView.Center = new CGPoint(xpos, ypos);
        };
        UIViewPropertyAnimator propertyAnimator = new UIViewPropertyAnimator(0.25, UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut, keyboardUnShift);
        propertyAnimator.StartAnimation();
    });
}
```

Hope somebody help me with this.

Comment: can you post the Exception stacktrace?

Comment: @StamatisStiliats No.

Comment: add `try catch` inside method `EditingChanged ` and `UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow` to catch the error message.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT It will not help, because there are no any error in simulator, and I haven't 6s device with iOS v10.2.1

Comment: @AdeptusMechanicus You should a crash reporter to your app to capture the stacktraces of the crash, otherwise you are just guessing as to the cause.

Comment: @SushiHangover You mean "try-catch" everywhere in the code?

Comment: @AdeptusMechanicus No, MS Azure provides one (one of many available on the market) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/crashes/

Comment: @SushiHangover Thank you. It will be very useful.